JS-HttpRequest + PHP: Form don't send file nor data
I'm trying to send a file and some text-based data using XMLHttpRequest. When I use
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

PHP gets nothing from the form sent. When I don't use it, PHP only gets the text field.
What am I missing?
HTML + Javascript
    <script>
      function saveFiles(){
        orderID = document.getElementById("orderID").value;

        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("orderID", orderID);
        formData.append("pdf_file", pdf_file);

        xhttp.open("POST", "testePHP.php", true);
        //xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        xhttp.send(formData);

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            alert(xhttp.responseText);  
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="orderID" name="orderID">
    <input class="form-control" type="file" name="pdf_file" id="pdf_file" >
    <input type="button" onclick="saveFiles()" value="send">
  </form>

PHP code:
$orderID = $_REQUEST["orderID"] ?? 0;
echo $orderID . "<br><br><br><br><br>";
echo $_FILES['pdf_file']['error'] . "]";

Response when I use xhttp.setRequestHeader:
b>Warning:  Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0
Warning:  Undefined array key "pdf_file" in C:\Users\liban\Documents\Dropbox_htdocs\kpi\testePHP.php on line 4

Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\Users\liban\Documents\Dropbox_htdocs\kpi\testePHP.php on line 4

You're setting a value to orderId here: orderID = document.getElementById("orderID").value;  Arguments about the evils of implicit globals aside... Where do you ever set a value for pdf_file?  If you're relying on the implicit global to be a reference to the <input> element, (1) that's a bad idea, and (2) why treat it differently in these two cases?

On Javascript, orderID and pdf_file come from html form.... I have to get the value from the element in order to put them in the dataForm.
It works fine when I use only text data.

The linked duplicate has sample code, as do many others.  You need to attach the actual selected file to the FormData element, not either the <input> element itself or whatever other unknown value pdf_file has in your code.

Thanks, David, but I still have two doubts:

How to attach the actual selected file to the FormData? and
Why the other values are not passed to the PHP?
Thank you!


"How to attach the actual selected file to the FormData?" - Look at the linked duplicate.  See what it's adding to FormData for the file.  For example: formData.append("pdf_file", document.querySelector('#pdf_file').files[0]);  Note how that's different from your code, where you never reference the files array on that element or even explicitly give any value to pdf_file at all.  "Why the other values are not passed to the PHP?" - According to your question, they are: "When I don't use it, PHP only gets the text field."

Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!
